# preventing an element that has already been inserted into an array from being reinserted

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running into a issue with pushing a value into an array. It works fine at first but if I re-click a element that is already in the array, it moves (pushes) it to the end of the array. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];

    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        var txt = $.trim(e);

        if ($.inArray(txt, result) == -1) {
            // pushing the element onto the end
            // and returning it
            // sorting is not the issue
            result.push(e);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });

    // sort 
    result.sort();

    return result.join(", ");
}
```

An example is that I click on a.php and then b.php and that works fine, a.php is sorted before b.php but if I click on a.php again, b.php is moved up to the front of the array. Is there a way to check this so it won't happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the click listener after the first use?

Comment: If this is jQuery, please tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are more robust answers to this question than the one I'm going to give. But I think you're looking for a straight, more or less naive answer (e.g. you're not looking to reengineer to ES6, you're not going to introduce another library, etc).

You can use Array.prototype.find.

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
function insertIfNoDupes ( num ) {
    if ( ! arr.find ( num ) ) {
      arr.push ( num );
    } else {
      console.log ( 'Value already exists in array' );
    }
}
```

Find will return undefined if the value isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom value to the element. For example I have 4 buttons

```
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Click me" onclick="addToArr(this)"><br/>
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="Click me" onclick="addToArr(this)"><br/>
<input id="btn3" type="button" value="Click me" onclick="addToArr(this)"><br/>
<input id="btn4" type="button" value="Click me" onclick="addToArr(this)"><br/>
```

and an array variable

```
var arr [];
```

I just need to add a custom value to the element if the value is not defined

```
function addToArr(elem){
    //If the element does not have 'addedToArr' defined, 
    //or the value of 'addedToArr' is not 'false' (which makes the condition true)
    if (!elem.addedToArr){ 
        arr.push(elem.id); //Push the element's id into array
        elem.addedToArr = true; //Set 'addedToArr' of the element to true
    }
    alert(arr.length); //This will alert the new length of the array
}
```